# Sitecore DMS Poll Module with Sitecore 7 issue

Tags: module, sitecore, sitecore7

We have installed the Sitecore DMS poll module with Sitecore 7 (https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Poll_Module.aspx) and it seems to work fine. The only issue we are having is, if you submit the poll without choosing any of the options, we get the following error: "Poll module error: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)." Anyone has experienced this before?

I am aware that Sitecore 7 is not mentioned as one of the supported versions in the module, but it does seem to work ok other than this issue.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please share stack trace of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally spotted the issue. Looks like in the JavaScript file Poll.js, in function *DMSPoll.RaiseCallBack*, value of variable *checkedOptionId* is compared against empty string but the value returned when no option is selected is *undefined*.

So I had to change the line from:
`if (checkedOptionId != "")` to 
`if (checkedOptionId != "" && typeof checkedOptionId != 'undefined')`.

Hope it saves someone else some time!